# iOS8 navigationBar top right corner of the black

Tags: ios, navigationbar

iOS8／iphone

When setting

```
navigationbar.translucent = yes;
```

If also set

```
blueVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = yes;
```

pushViewController, navigationbar right corner displays a black.

=======================

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;
```

This approach will lead to push the process tabbar disappear.

Comment: Please specify what language/platform/browser you're trying this on.

Comment: iOS8／iphone :) @mjuarez